# Como fixar a quantidade de caracteres numéricos de um float?

Tags: python, float

Escrevi um simples código onde no final de uma operação matemática preciso que o resultado saia com sete caracteres numéricos independe de onde estiver o ponto. Infelizmente eu só consigo ajustar a precisão das casas decimais mas eu preciso algo assim: 10.0000 ou 1000.01 ou 0.00007 o "tamanho" do número precisa sempre ser truncado com 7 caracteres.
Por exemplo, para o resultado: -3.1700000000419095 0.0 0.0 preciso ajustar para: -3.1700 0.00000 0.00000

Comment: E se o resultado necessitar mais de 7 caracteres, tal como 10 000 000? É impossível obter um valor assim nas operações feitas? E como questionado nas perguntas, o ponto e o sinal de negativo devem contar dentro deste limite de 7? Pois você especifica sete caracteres numéricos, mas no exemplo coloca apenas 5, pois existe o ponto e sinal de menos.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

Você pode fazer isso calculando o tamanho da parte unitária, se é negativo ou não, e depois arredondar o número de acordo com os números anteriores.

```
def num_to_7_char(num):
    if num == 0:
        return "0.00000"

    int_part = int(log10(abs(num))) + 1
    minus_part = int(num < 0)
    round_to = max(6 - int_part - minus_part, 0)

    return "{num:.{round_to}f}".format(num=num, round_to=round_to)
```

<sup>Código funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-353262-6333)</sup>

## Explicação

Se o número for zero, retorna `0.00000` pois não se pode calcular um logaritmo de 0.

Para calcular a parte unitária do número utilizo o método [`math.log10`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log10) para saber quantas *casas* o número tem, calculando quantas vezes eu tenho que multiplicar o número `10` para chegar no número desejado. Ex.:

```
from math import log10

print(log10(1))    # 0
print(log10(10))   # 1
print(log10(100))  # 2
```

Utilizo o método [abs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs) para pegar o módulo de um número, pois para calcular um logaritmo o número deve ser maior que 0.

Utilizo [int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) para converter o resultado para um inteiro e somo `1` para que o cálculo corresponda ao número de dígitos unitários do número.

Para calcular o espaço que vai ser ocupado pelo caractere `-` (sinal de menos) faço uma simples conversão de boolean para inteiro, onde `True` se tornará `1` e `False` se tornará `0`.

A variável `round_to` guarda a quantidade que queremos nas casas decimais, pois esta dependerá de quantos caracteres estarão à esquerda do ponto.

O cálculo do arredondamento é feito diminuindo a parte inteira e a parte do sinal do total desejado. Neste caso o total desejado é 6, pois é preciso considerar que o ponto vai ocupar um caractere.

O [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) está sendo utilizado para que não ocorra o caso de `round_to` ser negativo, ele define limite mínimo para zero. Ex.:

```
max(1, 0)  # 1
max(0, 0)  # 0
max(-1, 0) # 0
```

No final é utilizado [formatação de strings](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) utilizando o método [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) para arredondar e limitar o número.
O site [PyFormat](https://pyformat.info/) tem bons exemplos para entender como funciona.

---

Veja que este modelo não funciona corretamente em alguns casos por motivos óbvios certos números não são possíveis de serem representados em 7 caracteres sem especificar algumas outras regras, como por exemplo:

- Número maiores que `9_999_999`: pois seriam necessários pelo menos 8 caracteres para representá-los.
- Números inteiros com 6 dígitos: O algoritmo utiliza a regra de converter um `int` para `float` e preencher os caracteres restantes com zeros a direita, porém se um número inteiro tem apenas 6 dígitos não é possível representá-lo pois só caberia adicionar um ponto, sem poder adicionar zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Use o básico:
"{0:.**quantidade de casas decimais**f}".format(**numero**)

```
>>>"{0:.2f}".format(1/7)
>>>'0,14'
>>>
>>>"{0:.5f}".format(1/2)
>>>'0.50000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Transforma numa string e depois recorta ele. Caso o numero seja menor que o tamanho que voce quer, preenche com zeros a esquerda:

```py
def numero_sete(numero):
    numero = float(numero)
    numero = str(numero)
    numero = numero[:7]
    numero = numero.ljust(7, '0')

    return numero

numero_sete(-3.1700000000419095)
'-3.1700'
numero_sete(0.01)
'0.01000'
```

Comment: Se você fizer `numero_sete(1)` retorna `1000000` ao invés de `1.00000`, então é interessante garantir que o valor tratado seja `float`, fazendo `str(float(numero))`

Comment: Realmente. Como todos os exemplos dele eram float, eu pensei que isso fosse um requisito

Comment: E uma alternativa ao `ljust` é utilizar o próprio `format`, mas acredito que não faça muita diferença: `'{0:0<7}'.format(str(float(test))[:7])`

Answer (score 0):

```
def trunca_sete(num):
    return '%.7s' % (str(num).ljust(7, '0'))

trunca_sete(-3.1700000000419095)
'-3.1700'
trunca_sete(0.0)
'0.00000'
trunca_sete(1000.01)
'1000.01'
trunca_sete(1000.0199999)
'1000.01'
```